# FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\FormException' not found

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, autocomplete, symfony-2.3

When I tried to use `ShtumiUsefulBundle`'s `Ajax autocomplete type` i got the following error..

> FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\FormException' not found in /var/www/example.com/vendor/Shtumi/UsefulBundle/Form/Type/AjaxAutocompleteType.php line 52

My project is Symfony2.3.
Please help.

Comment: Please, paste some relevant code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`ShtumiUsefulBundle` is incompatible with your Symfony version. Try to find another bundle or implement your own for needed features or downgrade your Symfony to 2.0.